# JsRender range in JsReport

Tags: jsreport

My template crashes with 500 - Internal server error. when I attempt to use the range functionality that's part of jsRender. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Sample code

```
  {{range start=1 end=10}}
     <option>data</option>
  {{/range}}
```

or

```
 {{range start=0 end=:data }}
         <option>data</option>
 {{/range}}
```

Comment: Can you share with us the failing template? What do you mean by the range functionality?

Comment: @JanBlaha I added the sample code. I have an integer that is part of my data  set and I would like to output html from 0 to the integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range` is not a native jsrender tag. It is just used in the sample showing jsrender custom tag. However you can achieve such a behavior simply with custom helper function and `for` tag.

helper function

```
function range(start, end) {
    return _.range(start, end);
}
```

content

```
{{for ~range(0, 10)}}
    <h1>{{:#index}}</h1>
{{/for}}
```

[playground example here](https://playground.jsreport.net/#playground/e7JiDeKsfm/8)